# Using UIPageViewController to sign-up user

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on the user sign-up part of an iOS app and I am trying to use page views to get user input. So, the first page view takes the user's first name, the next one takes takes last name, phone number. Then the user receives a verification code which is put in by the user in the next page view. Only when the verification code is correct the user is allowed to go to (swipe right) to the next page view.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to trap the user input in the properties of my view controller which derives from UIPageViewController.

I am using :

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSUInteger index = [(SignupChildViewController *)viewController index];

    SignupChildViewController *current=(SignupChildViewController *)viewController;

    NSLog(@"%@", current.userCredentials.text);

    if(index==3)
    {
        firstPass=YES;
        if([verificationCodeUser isEqualToString:verificationCode])
        {
            verificationPassed=YES;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh snap!" message:@"You haven't entered the correct verification code." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
    if(index==3)
    {
        firstPass=YES;
    }


    index++;

    if (index == 6) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self updateInfo:index];
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

The updateInfo method looks something like this:

```
(void)updateInfo:(NSInteger)ind
{


    switch ([ind integerValue])
    {
        case 0:
            firstName=textview.text;
            break;
        case 1:
            lastName=textview.text;
            break;
        case 2:
            phoneNumber=textview.text;
            break;
        case 3:
            verificationCodeUser=textview.text;
            break;
        case 4:
            birthday=textview.text;
            break;
        case 5:
            password=textview.text;
            break;
    }
}
```

Here based on the index of the page, appropriate property is set. But the problem is that the property is sometimes getting set correctly, but at times it just gets an empty string in the textview even though the user has entered a string. How do I capture the user input while using pageviews?

Answer (score 0):

`viewControllerAfterViewController:` is a bad place to call `updateInfo:` because you're assuming you've already transitioned to that index when it may not be the case. `viewControllerAfterViewController:` can be called during cases other than a successful transition.

Instead, try updating the info during the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` methods [`pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDelegate/pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:) or [`pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDelegate/pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:) so you know for sure the view has transitioned or will transition.